# Define array from another array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to define an array starting from data that come from another array. 
The code will explain the situation better than thousands words.

```
public class QualityCheck {



public QualityCheck (JTable table)
{
    //the data come from a JTable (that represents a school timetable)
    String [] dailyLessons= new String[table.getColumnCount()];
    String [] dailyClasses= new String[table.getColumnCount()];

    //checking all the days
    for (int i=1; i<table.getColumnCount(); i++)
    {
        //checking all the hours in a day
        for (int j=0; j<table.getRowCount(); j++)
        {
            //lesson is an array that contains the subject and the room in which the subject is erogated
            //lesson[0] contains the subject
            //lesson[1] contains the room
            String[] lesson = ((TabellaOrario.MyTableModel)table.getModel()).getLesson(j,i);

            //I'd like to put ALL the daily subjects in dailyLesson
            dailyLessons[j] = lesson[0];

            //I'd like to put All the daily rooms in dailyClasses
            dailyClasses[j] = lesson[1];

        }

        //trying if dailyLessons has the elements
        for (String s: dailyLessons)
        {
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }   
}
}
```

If a run this code, the compiler protest with this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

and it evidence the string

```
dailyLessons[j] = lesson[0];
```

How can I do to define dailyLesson?

Comment: +1 for this "The code will explain the situation better than thousands words."

Comment: What does `table.getColumnCount()` return? (Or what is the length of `dailyLessons`?)

Comment: table.getColumbCount() return the number of column in a table. dailyLessons is an array with all the subjects that are erogated in a single day (represented by a column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are allocating **both** of the arrays to the same size `table.getColumnCount()`,
and then you use index `j` for **both** of them again, which goes up to `table.getRowCount() - 1`.

You probably should allocate one of them to size `table.getRowCount()`, and then use `j` as the index for only that one, and `i` for the other, but you never use `dailyClasses` so I'm not sure.

**Edit:**
Apparently the intent is to fill both the arrays with the data of one column. Then the fix is to change the size of the arrays to the amount of rows:

```
// Changed table.getColumnCount() -> table.getRowCount()
String [] dailyLessons= new String[table.getRowCount()];
String [] dailyClasses= new String[table.getRowCount()];
```

Comment: Hi kiheru and thanks for trying to help me. I can use `j` for both array, because I want to define the same location for each array. But, I repeat, I don't know why it does not work

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now what you are trying to do. I'll edit the answer a bit

Comment: Kiheru, I have resolved. I was wrong to define the array. The right one is:

`String [] dailyLessons= new String[table.getRowCount()];


    String [] dailyClasses= new String[table.getRowCount()];`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You init the arrays with `table.getColumnCount()` and loop using `j < table.getRowCount()`.

If `table.getColumnCount()` is smaller that `table.getRowCount()` then you will get AIOBE.

You need at least to init the arrays with `table.getRowCount()`.

**EDIT**

You could create a little class with encapsulates `dailyLessons` and `dailyClasses`

```
class Lesson {
    public String dailyLesson;
    public String dailyClass;
}
```

and create an array of that class, this way you'll always have the same number of daily lessons and classes:

```
String [] lessons = new Lesson [table.getRowCount()];
```

and later inside the loop:

```
lessons.dailyLesson = lesson[0];
lessons.dailyClass = lesson[1];
```

Also you could use an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of a simple array so you wont have to bother about the size of the array.

Comment: You're right, I will provide. Thank you. I would have appreciated a snippet to understand what were you saying

Comment: @Bernheart, glad i could help. I guess the snipet you were looking for was provided by kiheru. I have little addition, see my edit.